# Why doesn't my compiler think more about optimization?

Tags: optimization, compilers

This happens to me from time to time: I compile my code with the highest optimization level (`-Ofast`) of the allegedly fastest compiler (GCC) of one of the fastest languages (C/C++). It takes 3 seconds. I run the compiled program, measuring performance. Then I make some trivial change (say, marking a function `inline`), compile it again, and it runs 20% faster.

Why? Often I'd rather wait a few minutes or even hours, but be sure that my code is at least hard to optimize further. Why does the compiler give up so quickly?

As far as I know modern architectures are super complicated and hard to a priori optimize for. Couldn't a compiler test many possibilities and see which one is the fastest? I effectively do this by making random changes in the source code, but that doesn't sound optimal.

Comment: gcc is open source, so you can download the source code, compile it, modify it and have your question answered that way.

Comment: @gnasher729 Do you mean for me to add the "thinking more" to it? I don't know how to, and I'm looking for a high-level reason why it isn't done in general.

Comment: What you ask for has been done, and it has been done specifically for GCC, so I am curious why you think it "can't be done"?

Comment: @JörgWMittag Can you expand on that "has been done [...] for GCC"? I didn't say what you quoted

Comment: What makes you think that it can't be done?  Whether or not gcc actually does it seems irrelevant to whether it could be done.  Are you really asking why gcc doesn't do it?  If so, I'm not sure that is on-topic here.

Comment: @D.W. I only used "can't" in the title, I didn't mean to say that it is impossible to do at all, sorry if that misled you. I only used GCC as an example because it's said to produce the fastest code.

Comment: I don't understand what distinction you are drawing between "can't" and "impossible".  Perhaps I don't understand what you are asking or what you think or why you think that.  It seems obvious that a compiler could do that; I'm not sure what more there is to say about that.  The extent to which each compiler does that, and why, will differ for each compiler.  If you're asking specifically why GCC doesn't do that, I'm not sure that's on-topic here.  If you're asking about all compilers, I'm not sure there will be any answer.  Can you figure out a better way to articulate your question?

Comment: @D.W. I didn't mean to draw a distinction there, with the title I basically meant "why doesn't".

Comment: Please [edit] the question to reflect what you wanted to ask, and to address the feedback you've received.  Comments exist to try to help you improve your question.  Don't leave clarifications in the comments -- instead, revise the question and make it read well for someone who encounters it for the first time, so they don't have to read the comments to understand what you're asking.  I notice you haven't answered my other questions.